# Excel Macro calculate end date provided with start date and task time

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I need to calculate the end date provided that start date and task time is provided. With excel WorkDay formula we get the end date but remaining time should be carry forwrded to other row and end date again needs to be evaluated. Following is the start sheet as in excel.

[Empty end dates with one start date and task times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcNHq.png)
As seen if we assume 8 working hours/day, and use the Workday formula we can have end date in each row. What is actual required is the auto start date in next row with consideration of balance time (if any) from the previous task.
Following is the final excel sheet which is required.

[Completed Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTnzH.png)
If macro is used i am okay with it. The final complete sheet should consider the balance time (if we assume 8 hrs/day as working hour) of previous task and then calculate the end date.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: You need to at least attempt to do this first. Stack overflow isnt a code writing service, but we are happy to assist if you are stuck

Comment: Also, instead of posting images, post some data that we can copy-paste to try it. And post your efforts trying to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA for this. Calculate a cumulative time, check the quocient with 8, then use that to calculate the end day.

I'd love to post only images as you did, but I won't be that mean. :)

[image: Calculation]

**Formulas:**

```
B2    =A2
B3    =A3+B2
C2    =QUOTIENT(B2,8)
D2    2016-08-08
D3    =E2
E2    =WORKDAY($D$2,C2)
```

Obviously pull the formulas down.

Basically the QUOTIENT function is used to determine the number of 8 hours passed since the beginning.

Hope this helps, if you can't understand something, keep looking at it or go ahead and ask! :)

Comment: Thanks vacip, it worked, I was not aware of quotient function, thank a ton:-)

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. Please mark it as the answer then!

Comment: Glad to my friend, help me out where to mark your answer as answer?